# Is this a proper way to use a transistor?

Tags: transistors, npn

Are there any problems with the way this works, or a more effecient way of doing this? Although this works fine on my breadboard I feel this may be improper. I was unsure where to put the negative terminal of the battery which switches the transistor, and putting it on the collector seems to work. Is this because it flows from the base, to the battery, and then from the battery to the collector, allowing the larger current to flow to the emitter, or is that logic all screwed up? Thank you :)
[image: My Schematic]

Comment: No. this is completely wrong.

Comment: A more efficient way is just put a 3V battery in series with Switch to a Green LED for about the same current as 510 to 1k to 9V.  Or use a 3.7V LiPo with 0.5 V drop to 50 Ohms for 10 mA.  At these low currents a transistor isn't necessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to use a transistor to control something is :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMEDgy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 ensured that the transistor is held Off when the switch is open.  R3 limits the base current to a safe value for the transistor.  R2 limits the LED current to a safe value for the LED.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you, that makes sense. Good thing I asked, lol. I would have thought what I was doing was correct, but I had a feeling I had it all wrong.

Comment: @GuyBartkus and this is an example of a better way to present schematics on this site, positive to the top, ground at the bottom, flow left to right, using the schematic editor available in the post editor.

Answer (score 5):

Swizzle around your connections to be like this. The batteries share common GND connections with the NPN emitter and the base pulldown resistor.

[image]

Comment: +1 for pedantic cut-n-paste (or is it origami?) This adaptation is nicely compatible with microcontrollers, with  9v battery negative going to microcontroller ground, and microcontroller output pin substituting for VCC1.

Answer (score 0):

Your circuit works, there are situations when a resistor from collector to base is used for voltage(http://pcbheaven.com/wikipages/images/trans_theory_1318867839.png). There are also situations when you connect the LED to emitter. VCC1 is strangely placed though. What are you trying to do?